# Webstorm 11 build-in server returns 404

Tags: debugging, webstorm

My default port for build-in server is 63342:

[image]

Also I've got JetBrains browser plugin installed

I just added Javascript debug configuration:
But getting this 404 error in borwser:

[image]

[image]

How to fix that?

p.s
Also I probably should point that I am trying to debug angular2 application it it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just 1 idea - I can see that your actual project path (ng2-intro-my) differs from the one in URL (ng2intro). This may be the issue